# replace different text in different lines using sed

Tags: bash

I need to do the following:

I have two files, the first one contains only the lines that are going to be modified:

```
1
2
3
```

and the second contains the text that is going to be replaced in original file (final_output.txt)

```
13e
19f
16a
```

the original file is

```
wire1: 0x'd318   
wire2: 0x'd415   
wire3: 0x'd362
```

I want to get the following:

```
wire1: 0x13e
wire2: 0x19f
wire3: 0x16a
```

This is only a part of final_output.txt, because the file can contain at least 100 lines, and I pretend to do it using for, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Could you edit your question to show a more elaborate example of the contents of input files 1 and 2 and then the expected output. At least to me the relationships between the files are not obvious as the question is now. Check the editor help to make sure you show different lines (using the code notation).

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

assuming the part after the single quote will be replaced.

```
$ awk -v q="'" 'NR==FNR  {a[$1]=$2;next} 
                FNR in a {sub(q".*",a[FNR])}1' <(paste index rep) file
```

`index` is the index file, `rep` is the replacement file, and `file` is the original data file.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution where file1 contains only the lines, file2 contains the text that is going to be replaced in original file and final_output.txt contains your original text.

```
for ((i=1;i<=$(wc -l < file1);i++)); do sed -i "$(sed -n "${i}p" file1)s@$(sed -n "$(sed -n "${i}p" file1)p" final_output.txt | grep -oP "'.*")@$(sed -n "${i}p" file2)@g" final_output.txt; done
```

**Output**

```
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$ cat final_output.txt
wire1: 0x13e
wire2: 0x19f
wire3: 0x16a
darby@Debian:~/Scrivania$
```